# Unused variable warning even when explicitly using it inside IF statement

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++17

I am trying to create (using C++17) a simple debug header that only executes some lines of code if the flag **LOGGER_DEBUG_MODE** is enabled. This is how my header is defined (I also tried using **{ x; }** instead of **x** but the warning persists):

*debug.h*

```
#ifndef _HDEBUG

    #define _HDEBUG

    static bool LOGGER_DEBUG_MODE = true;
    #define R_DEBUG(x) if(LOGGER_DEBUG_MODE == true) x
    
#endif
```

I included *debug.h* and at some point of my code I call the macro function **R_DEBUG** to print some values:

*logger_adc.cpp*

```
double anlg_device_t::eval_formula()
{
    double result = -9999;

    try
    {
        result = parser.Eval();
    }
    catch (mu::Parser::exception_type &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.GetMsg() << std::endl;
    }

    R_DEBUG(std::cout << "Eval Result: " << result << std::endl);

    return result;
}
```

I expected everything to work properly but when I run the makefile I got this warning:

> inc/debug.h:5:14: warning: 'LOGGER_DEBUG_MODE' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
> static bool LOGGER_DEBUG_MODE = true;

I thought that my definition was messed up but after checking the temporary files created by g++, it appears that the preprocessor did everything as I expected:

*logger_adc.ii*

```
double anlg_device_t::eval_formula()
{
    double result = -9999;

    try
    {
        result = parser.Eval();
    }
    catch (mu::Parser::exception_type &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.GetMsg() << std::endl;
    }

    if(LOGGER_DEBUG_MODE == true) std::cout << "Eval Result: " << result << std::endl;

    return result;
}
```

Why do I get the warning message even when the variable **LOGGER_DEBUG_MODE** is clearly being used inside the **if** statement? Did I mess up something obvious that I'm not picking up? My compile flags for the object files (where the warning occurs) are `g++ -Wall -Wextra -O1 -g -std=c++17 -save-temps=obj -Iinc -I/usr/local/include -c` plus `pkg-config --cflags --libs libmodbus`

If needed, this is my **main** function:

*main.cpp*

```
#include "logger_adc.h"

int main()
{
    anlg_device_t test (ADC_CHIP_1, 1, 18, 1, 1, true);
    test.set_formula("2*x","x", test.get_voltage_ptr());

    std::cout << "Test Voltage: " << test.get_voltage() << std::endl << "Test Relative: " << test.get_relative() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Test Formula (2*x): " << test.eval_formula() << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a general hint, related to your issue: Do not try to build control flows via static (const) variables if possible. If a compile time switch is required (which looks it is the case here actually), only use compile time schemes here if possible (#ifdefs or constexpr since C++17).

Comment: `#define _HDEBUG` That name is reserved for the language implementation. By defining it, your program will have undefined behaviour. You should use another name for your macro.

Comment: @eerorika Changed it to `_HLOGGERDEBUG`, thanks!

Comment: @LucasVaz That name is also reserved. You should choose another.

Comment: @eerorika zzzzzz, changed it to `_HDATALOGGERSIGMADEBUG`. If this is reserved, I give up.

Comment: @eerorika I just searched it, why didn't you just say that any name that begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved ?

Comment: @LucasVaz I wanted you to *learn how to learn* language rules on your own. It's a valuable skill to a programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a header that defines a `static bool LOGGER_DEBUG_MODE =true;`. If you include that header in multiple C++ files then *each file will gets its own copy of that bool*.

In your main.cpp you aren't using `R_DEBUG` so the copy of that bool (which presumably comes from including `logger_adc.h` ) is indeed unused in that file.

Possible solutions are:

You should make it so you only have a single copy of that bool (declare it in the header with `extern` and define it in a single C++ file.

Use build defines instead of runtime checks

etc

Comment: I thought that static variables were already shared between the objects, that explains a lot. So it will become something like `extern bool LOGGER_DEBUG_MODE;` in the header and `bool LOGGER_DEBUG_MODE = true;` in the main (for example) ?

Comment: Static is an overloaded term in C++. In a class, a `static` variable is indeed shared between all instances of that class. As a global variable, `static` means its local to that C++ file (technically _translation unit_)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static explains the 3 different uses of static - I forgot function local statics :-)